# Calculate the days it took to clear each bills with partial payments in excel

Tags: excel

I have a CSV file with the following info:

```
Date        Bills       Payment
31-08-14    490882  
03-09-14                -200000
03-09-14    950880  
04-09-14                -600000
06-09-14    1028976.8   
08-09-14                -668000
09-09-14        
09-09-14    368616.4    
10-09-14                -750000
12-09-14    1111322.6   
13-09-14    737780.4    
14-09-14                -50000
18-09-14                -425000
21-09-14                -1000000
```

Here is the CSV file: https://docs.zoho.com/file/9de9d171bda4412374843adde73f5249f5c8c

I need to calculate the days it took to pay each Bill.

**Problem:** there lies some balance after each partial payment.

For each `Bills > 0`, I need to SUM Payment column UNTIL `-(Bill) <= SUM of Payment`. And calculate the days.

### Update:

I made a separate column for each bill and ran this formula:
`=IF($E$3:$E5>-$D$3,"",TEXT($B$6-$B$3,"DD")&" Days")`

On the following excel sheet: [Link to Excel Sheet](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?page=view&resid=132F6BB8DDEF9E04!739&authkey=!AI8y2cAoTOOE5zQ)

Comment: It's generally expected to see some original effort at solving the problem, working or not. If you have a formula that you were working on but it is not producing the correct results, edit your question to include it and explain what the expected result should be.

Comment: I created 2 columns with running totals of Bills and Payment. And added another column containing the subtraction values of those two. But it didn't help. Then again tried to solve it manually by breaking the formula apart.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula

```
=IF(B2="","",IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$10,MATCH(TRUE,SUMIF(A$2:A$10,"<="&A$2:A$10,C$2:C$10)<=-SUM(B$2:B2),0)),"Unpaid"))
```

I'm just testing it on a small number of rows so that I can follow the arithmetic more easily.

It finds which is the earliest dated payment you need to include to clear the current bill and all previous bills.

Must be entered as an array formula starting in D2 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then to find the days elapsed, in E2:-

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(D2),D2-A2,"")
```

[image]

Comment: It only works for first few rows. How to make it work for whole workbook? It's not like, I am asking without not trying to do it myself.... I tried to extend the range, but couldn't solve.

Comment: It's possible to change A$2:A$10 to A:A, but I don't recommend it because it is slow. Just change the end of the range to whatever you think will be enough,  e.g. =IF(B2="","",IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$1000,MATCH(TRUE,SUMIF(A$2:A$1000,"<="&A$2:A$1000,C$2:C$1000)<=-SUM(B$2:B2),0)),"Unpaid"))